# IIS is returning JSON instead of File (in Export to Excel functionality)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js, iis-8

I have a web application that's being hosted on IIS 8.  It uses VueJS, and ASP.NET Web API.  It has the ability to export a grid to Excel, which works in our TEST environment, but doesn't work in our Production environment.  In TEST, when the user clicks on the Export to Excel button, it allows the user to download the XLSX document in the web browser.  But in Production, it returns JSON.

Here's the code I'm using to stream out the file:

```
var appRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");

                        var savePath = string.Format("{0}\\Temporary_Files\\{1}.xlsx", appRoot, Guid.NewGuid());
                
                        workbook.SaveAs(savePath);
                        
                        HttpResponseMessage document = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

                        var stream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Open);

                        document.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

                        document.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");

                        document.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Export.xlsx";

                        document.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                        document.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

                        return document;
```

Here's the response in TEST:

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 7713
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.xlsx
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 17:50:54 GMT
```

Here's the response in Production:

RESPONSE HEADERS

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 17:45:02 GMT
Content-Length: 373
```

RESPONSE BODY

```
{"Version":{"_Major":1,"_Minor":1,"_Build":-1,"_Revision":-1},"Content":{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Disposition","Value":["attachment; filename=Export.xlsx"]},{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/octet-stream"]},{"Key":"Content-Length","Value":["7497"]}]},"StatusCode":200,"ReasonPhrase":"OK","Headers":[],"RequestMessage":null,"IsSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

Comment: According to the code you provided, I tested it but there was no problem. I think if it might be a path problem. The xlsx file was not found correctly in IIS. You can try to use the absolute path to read xlsx to see if there is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try my way:

```
return File(bytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                reportFilename + "." + extension)
```